# Maven plugin for junit/testng generation

Tags: maven, testing

Are there any maven plugins for generating test stubs for a given java project? I am not looking for test case generation - I am looking for something like junitdoclet.

Context: We have a lot of legacy code without any test cases. Attempting to generate base stubs for all these classes. If successful - can be used with code coverage tools to add new test cases to the project with lesser effort.

Comment: What would be the difference to generate this stubs by IDE? Using the already mentioned code coverage tools missing testcases could be identified.

Comment: most developers in the team have their preferred IDEs... this will make the stubs generic. Once the generated stubs are in the repository - it will not matter which IDE individual developers use to add the logic.

Comment: Sorry. I still dont get it. Using junit 4 or testng meta info is annotated. So what are your concerns if eclipse or netbeans or whatever IDE generates a test method with an annotation? Why this generation process? Maybe I am not aware of some specific differences.

Answer (score 1):

Not a maven plugin - but this tool worked the best: 
https://code.google.com/p/randoop/